# RelativeLayout - Positioning item below the lowest of two Views

Tags: android

I have a TextView (width: fill_parent) in a RelativeLayout that I want to ensure is under the the two Views above it that are side by side, with dynamic widths and height. That means, that sometimes the Left view is taller and sometimes the Right View is taller.

I tried to have two "below" parameters set, but that is not allowed of course.
I tried to modify it through code (with the XML having it set below the txt TextView, and img being the ImageView beside it):

```
if (txt.getHeight() + txt.getTop() < img.getHeight() + img.getTop()) {
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
                    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.image);
                    txtDetails.setLayoutParams(params);
                }
```

(txtDetails is the one that I want below both views).

When that didn't work (nothing changed), I put txtDetails in its own RelativeLayout below the RelativeLayout that housed both views and that worked.  However, I feel that RL should be able to handle this situation, without creating a new RL.  Is it possible? Or what is the best way to position this view?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible problem with your code:
You are calling getHeight() on a view, and that might return 0 if a layout pass hasn't been done yet. you should put the entire code in a GlobalLayoutListener like so:

```
getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
   @Override
   public void onGlobalLayout() {
       // your code here...
       txt.requestLayout(); // Add this to ensure your changes are applied.
   }
}
```

PS. you can just call `txt.getBottom()` instead of `txt.getHeight() + txt.getTop()`

Answer (score 2):

why not use a tablelayout? It does exactly what you want in 2 rows.

First add the two variable views in one row and after that, add another row containing your textview.

Like this:

```
<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/center"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    <TableRow >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="150sp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/lorem_short" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="150sp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:text="@string/lorem_long" />
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5sp"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```